# ip routing table basics

Tags: linux, ip, router

Could you please explain the following basic ip routing table:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface

10.80.0.0       192.176.20.1    255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 eth0

192.176.100.0   *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 int1

10.1.1.0        192.176.20.1    255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 eth0

10.13.1.0       192.176.100.1   255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 int1

192.176.0.0     *               255.255.0.0     U     1      0        0 eth0

default         192.176.20.2    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

Comment: This may be a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8599424/understanding-routing-table-entry/29882884#29882884

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you have 2 local interfaces on the router; `eth0` and `int1`. I guess it's easiest to go through line by line of the routing table.

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
10.80.0.0       192.176.20.1    255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

This states that any packet with a destination of `10.80.0.0/24` will be sent out eth0 using a gateway of `192.176.20.1`.

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface   
192.176.100.0   *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 int1
```

This states that any packet with a destination of `192.176.100.0/24` will be sent out int1 without using a gateway.

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
10.1.1.0        192.176.20.1    255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

This states that any packet with a destination of `10.1.1.0/24` will be sent out eth0 using a gateway of `192.176.20.1`.

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
10.13.1.0       192.176.100.1   255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 int1
```

This states that any packet with a destination of `10.13.1.0/24` will be sent out int1 using a gateway of `192.176.100.1`.

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.176.0.0     *               255.255.0.0     U     1      0        0 eth0
```

This states that any packet with a destination of `192.176.0.0/16` will be sent out eth0 without using a gateway.

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.176.20.2    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

This states that any packet that doesn't match any of the above routes will be forwarded out eth0 with a gateway of `192.176.20.2`. Most likely a route to the internet (also called Gateway of Last Resort, if I'm not mistaken).

If you need more information, don't hesitate to ask.

**Extra info on the specifics:** http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/what-is-a-routing-table/

Answer (score 2):

- Destination = the address of the network that the packet is headed to

The "default" means that if the destination is not found in any of the other rules, than use this rule.

- Genmask = The subnet mask

If there is more than one address in the routing table that works for the outgoing packet, the rule with the higher subnet mask will be used.  If those are tied, then metric comes into play but that will be different based on what  protocol is being used.

- Interface = On-board connection

For example, the laptop I am on currently has three interfaces:

1. Ethernet card
2. Wireless card
3. Bluetooth

Routers generally have at least 2 interfaces for each side, 1 for each network they are a part of. For most home routers, 1 interface is part of your home network and the other is part of the external network (usually the internet) headed toward your ISP.

- Gateway = Next hop

This is where the packet will be sent if the destination is not on the same network as the sender.

If the value is "*" or "On-link" or the address of the current device... these all mean the same thing.  It means that the packet is addressed to a device that is directly reachable by the current host.  In other words, they're on the same network so the gateway won't actually be used because the host will know the data link layer (MAC) address of the destination and be able to send it directly there. These values are just used for human readability in this case.

As for the process of sending a packet:

- Destination and Genmask are used to figure out which rules are a
  match for the destination address of the outgoing packet.
- Interface is used to decide what communication device on the machine
  to send it through.
- Gateway is the address of the device on the same network that it will
  send the packet to.

Comment: I just want to make sure I'm understanding gateway correctly: The gateway is the “next-hop” a packet should take in order to get to it’s destination, thus the default route has a next hop that gets the packet (hopefully) one step closer to it’s destination because in the case of default, the router does NOT know where that destination ip is. The star (*) simply means, no “next-hop” needed because that destination ip is on the network that router “serves.”

Comment: I think you got it.